# Is there a way to know if the ipa was archived vs just run directly in xCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I like to create slightly different code when running the app from within xCode vs when archiving in xCode.

is that possible somehow with a compiler setting that one cann access?

Just like **BuildConfig.DEBUG** on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to do this in Xcode is to use Schemes. They are already setup and you will see them under Edit Schemes. When you are running normally in Xcode, you are typically running the Debug Scheme, there is also a Scheme set up for "Archive" (basically a release build). Xcode supports setting up as many schemes as you like and to set one up takes only minutes.

In the example illustrated in the picture I've set a pre-processor flag "DEBUG" to be set to 1 when running the "Debug" Scheme, or debug mode in Xcode. It is NOT set in other schemes. This makes it possible to have code that is only included in Debug builds, and not included in Archive builds.

[image]

That's pretty much all it takes, then you simply do something like this in your code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    <Some code that is included and executed when running the Debug Scheme>
#else
    <Some other code that executes at other times in other Schemes>
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but still that does not really distinguish between running directly vs archiving. What you are suggesting is to have 2 schemes and use one for archiving and the other for debug/run directly from within xCode? Isn't there an easier way like a flag in code

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting two Schemes, and that is the recommended way to know if your running a Debug build in Xcode vs. an Archive build on outside Xcode. I will amend my answer a bit to show you. It is quite simple.

Comment: @user387184 *Isn't there an easier way like a flag in code* You can't **set** the flag in code because the code has no way to know how it's being run. You can **check** a flag in your code, though, and set the flag differently depending on how the project was built. You do that using a build scheme, as Cliff has suggested. This is the right answer.